# How can I get the arrow keys back in the centre of the SwiftKey keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, swiftkey

Until yesterday my SwiftKey keyboard showed arrow keys in the middle of the keyboard. I had switched on the thumb layout and the arrow keys for a compact yet functional layout.

Since yesterday (October 26, 2020) the arrow keys can only appear at the bottom, increasing the keyboard height with one full row.

The thumb layout still exists, but now just leaves an empty gap in the middle where the arrow keys were before.

How can I get the arrow keys back in the centre of the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinstall an older version, try one of the following sites to download.

- [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/swiftkey/)
- [APK4Fun](https://www.apk4fun.com/apk/10910/)
- [APKPure](https://apkpure.com/microsoft-swiftkey-keyboard/com.touchtype.swiftkey)

[Swiftkey version 7.6.5.7](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/swiftkey/swiftkey-keyboard/swiftkey-keyboard-7-6-5-7-release/) seems to be the latest version that has the arrow key + thumb keyboard functionality available.
You can download and install the linked `.apk` file.
After that you need to configure the Google Play store to not auto-update Swiftkey by following these steps:

1. Open Google Play store
2. Navigate to the Swiftkey app
3. Click the three dots in the upper right
4. Uncheck the box **Enable auto-update ⬜**.

<sub>Disclaimer: I take no responsibility for the apk's on these site.</sub>